# Textmate alternative with vim?

Tags: linux, vi

Is there a way to use the vim editor like the mac textmate editor ?
I am searching a easy configuration or plugin.

- a split screen or a panel for directorys
- currently opend files

or many cool stuff like textmate.

is there any plugin for the vi - vim editor or configuration tutorial aviable ?

Comment: this might be more appropriate for superuser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main plugins you might be interested in will be:

SnipMate (Textmate-like snippets), Nerdtree (directory browser), Minibufexplorer (manage multiple buffers) and taglist (Make use of C-tags for an object browser).

You can find these plugins and more at http://vim.org/

Comment: hey big thanks that are the stuff i am searching :)

Answer (score 4):

You could start by following http://blog.danielfischer.com/2010/11/19/a-starting-guide-to-vim-from-textmate/

Comment: The http://vimcasts.org site has some good videos which show how to do textmate things in Vim.

Answer (score 0):

[Vimmate](http://vimmate.rubyforge.org/) is an effort to do just what you ask. The only problem is that it seems abandonware. But it works for me.

[image]

You can try it by doing `sudo gem install VimMate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Textmate alternative for Linux. Try this

1) Gedit  with Gedit-gmate and Gedit-plugins
https://github.com/gmate/gmate

2) Redcar
https://github.com/redcar/redcar/wiki/installation

Answer (score 0):

Or, alternate approachs:

- [Vico](http://www.vicoapp.com/), editor with Vi keybindings and support for some TextMate bundles
- [TextMateVim](https://github.com/philc/textmatevim), TextMate plugin to add some Vi keybindings